# Suddenly Visual Studio Intellisense slowed down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intellisense

I'm working on a Unity project for days now and it was working totally fine, but then suddenly it became too slow whether for suggesting completion of code or removing the red underline (the code is working fine). I'm using VS2019 16.9.6.
[It is even slower than that (GIF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlLoA.gif)

GIF credits @mgear : https://forum.unity.com/threads/visual-studio-intellisense-slow-down.666412/

In developer community they said they fixed this issue in V16.1 but I'm already using V16.9? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-is-responding-too-slow/464979

I would be so grateful for any guidance, I tried a few tweaks but didn't work tho.